# Asynctask Download and set Jpg as imageView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

With help from internet, I can download a jpg and set it to ImageView with bitmap.
But, I want to keep it as jog or png.

How I can do that?

```
  public class GetFlickr  extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    private ProgressBar pBar;
    private String file = "flickr.xml";
    private WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;

  GetFlickr(ImageView Iv){
     imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(Iv);
  }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
      super.onPreExecute();
      pBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      pBar.setProgress(0);
      pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
      Bitmap bitmap=null;

      try{

        URL urlfinal = new URL("https://farm66.staticflickr.com/65535/49344706212_80c4e61053.jpg");
        HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlfinal.openConnection();
        connection1.connect();
        //FileOutputStream fOut2= openFileOutput("flickr.jpg", MODE_PRIVATE);
        InputStream fOut2 = urlfinal.openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fOut2);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
      pBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
      ImageView Iv = imageViewWeakReference.get();
      if (Iv != null){
        Iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
      pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good help will be the library [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

You can easily work with online images, automatic caching, etc.

just insert in your gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'
```

and load your image like this

```
Picasso.get().load(/* here your url */).into(imageView1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. it supports LruCache and diskCache.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
}
```

then load it as the following:

```
Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used glide before, but had no idea that it can load files from url